# Setting the height of an embedded pastebin item on a Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, pastebin

I have this [blog post](http://blog.publictalksoftware.co.uk/2018/03/22/620/) that I have been authoring. At the very bottom is an **Additional Information** expandable link:

[image: Example from blog post]

Within there are two links to pastebin code:

```
[pastebin id="uSP54JHz"]
[pastebin id="5hv0vYxy"]
```

The article is on a Wordpress site and I have a plugin called [Pastebin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/pastebin-embed/) installed. I have tried following the [advice](https://wordpress.org/plugins/pastebin-embed/#how%20do%20i%20set%20custom%20dimensions%20to%20my%20pastes%3F) to get the view of the pastebin code to use a smaller height instead of the full height for the code but I can’t get it to work.

> Since WordPress 4.2, you can double click the embedded item to set max width and max height. It will add the WordPress `[embed]` shortcode:
>
> `[embed width=”600″ height=”400″]http://pastebin.com/hcv2WRnX[/embed]`
>
> Note: Doing it the WordPress way, using the `[embed]` shortcode, is backwards and forward compatible, and it works with all the themes.

To be honest, I don’t see the point in specifying in pixels anyway. I just wondered if it could be reduced somehow. Kind of like StackOverflow view behaves.

Comment: Use your browser developer tools to inspect the markup produced by that shortcode. Find the main containing css class and try setting a max height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just set a max-height on the `.embedPastebin` in your CSS. I'm not sure about the embed shortcode (Note: the quotation marks in your example may not parse properly because they are `”` and `″` instead of `"`)

Using the following CSS works pretty well:

```
.embedPastebin {
    max-height: 300px;
}
```

[image]

If you want the `embedFooter` to always remain at the top, you can instead limit the size of the `ol` and change the `overflow` on it:

```
.embedPastebin ol {
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Fantastic. That looks much better. Thanks.